# Where can I read C99 official language standard manual/reference/specification online?

Tags: c, standards, specifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do I find the current C or C++ standard documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents)

Where can I read C99 official language standard manual/reference/specification online?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The official standard should not be available online — ISO and its national standards bodies would be unhappy about that.  You can obtain an official electronic copy from the ANSI store (http://webstore.ansi.org/) for <s>$18</s> $30 (or thereabouts — it was $18 when I obtained the C99 standard, but that was quite a while ago now; it was $30 for the C11 standard).  Or you can go to the web site linked in other answers (and via Wikipedia) — namely http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/ - and obtain almost official copies of the standards documents.

Comment: I can't believe that the official standard for one of the worlds most used and powerful languages is closed away like this.

Comment: @Jonathan, Is this how they make money? But surely the number of buyers would be extremely little to make up for any profit right?

Comment: I am merely describing the status quo, not defending it.  I have not studied the finances of ISO or ANSI or BSI…  On the whole, $30 is a reasonable value.  Buying the complete SQL standard requires a multi-thousand dollar layout (multiple parts at more than $300 each), which is much less reasonable.

Comment: Generally, standards are not light reading. I'd say they should pay money for people to read them :)

Answer (score 32):

The standard itself is [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)<sup>(a)</sup> (with TC1, 2 and 3 included), the rationale document is [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n897.pdf).

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Actually, it's the final draft but is still useful because:

- the changes from final draft to published standard are usually minimal to none; and
- it's free unlike the *actual* standards :-)

Answer (score 5):

Here's the [link](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n897.pdf) to the standard N897 C Standard Rationale and [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf)'s the full documentation N1124 as set down by ISO committee, here's a [wiki](http://clc-wiki.net/wiki/The_C_Standard) detailing about the standards

Comment: That draft is old!  Use @paxdiablo's link instead.

Answer (score 5):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99#References) links directly to it.